# How can I check to see if the index of a string is equal to a character?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Kitten";
    String test = 't';
    while (a.substring(0, 1) != test) {

    }
}
```

Basically I want to execute the code within the while loop until the substring is the letter 't'. I have no idea how I can have it check it. And I apologize I'm very new to java.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
String a = "Kitten";
char test = 't';

while(a.charAt(0) != test) {

}
```

Although from your question, it seems like you want to iterate through your string until you get to a 't'.  Then this would do the trick.

```
String a = "Kitten";
char test = 't';
int i = 0;

while(a.charAt(i) != test) {
    //
    // do stuff here
    //

    i++;
}
```

And if all you want is the index of the character 't', you can do this:

```
int indexOfTest = a.indexOf(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
    while (!a.substring(0, 1).equals(test)) {

    }
```

Now you may ask that, what is the difference between `!=` and using `!equals`.Actually `==` or `!=` operators check whether the references are same where equals method matches the value

Comment: Oh interesting! Thanks.

Comment: btw, also remember string intern concept, so
String test = "t";
String test1 = "t";
if(test == test1) will return true due to string pooling because both test and test1 point to same reference.